# Umbraco : creating custom property editor based on dropdown - not saving selection

Tags: umbraco7, custom-properties

I have been trying to build a custom property editor based on the dropdown.

I have managed to get it to build with a set of options based on a prevalues field, and when I edit the document with this editor, I see all the drop down options, but having selected one and saved the document, it does not save my selection. (I checked the back end db, and no value is being written)

I must be missing something?

code extracts...

***package.manifest***

...
        prevalues:{
                fields:[
                    {
                        label:"Options",
                        description: "Options",
                        key:"myOptions",
                        view:"multivalues"
                    },
...

***view***

<select  ng-model="model.value" ng-options="opt.id as opt.value for opt in model.config.myOptions">
         <option></option>
 </select>

Do I need to somehow bind them to the model?

ps just tested, if I hard code the options in the view it works fine. Hmm.....what do I do next!

Comment: When you select an option in the dropdown, you should assign that to the object `$scope.model.value`.

For example: `$scope.model.value = dropdownOptions[0]`

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I'll try that